# What is the difference between a keyword symbol and a quoted symbol?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols

What is the difference between the keyword symbol

```
:foo
```

and the quoted symbol:

```
'foo
```

Both stand for themselves, and can be used as an identifier. I can see that keyword symbols are mainly used for named parameters, but I was asking myself if it was not possible to implement this using quoted symbols as well?

In other words: Why do I need both?

Comment: You don't have to use keyword symbols as "keyword arguments"; it's just the default. I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23970123/1281433) that shows how you can use, e.g., quoted symbols as keyword names in lambda lists.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: though quoted symbols as keywords in argument lists seems to be used very rarely in the code bases I've seen.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I agree entirely.  I don't think I've ever see it in practice, to be honest, except maybe in emulating Scheme.  The only use case that I've thought of, really, would be using non-exported symbols to indicate that something isn't a *supported* keyword option, but it's still there.  E.g., maybe something like `(frob bar baz :from-end t 'frobber::include-debug-output t)`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First: `'something` is a shorter notation for `(quote something)`. The reader will transform the quote character into a list with the symbol `cl:quote` as the first item. For the evaluator it means: don't evaluate `something`, just return it as a result.

```
CL-USER 22 > '(quote foo)
(QUOTE FOO)

CL-USER 23 > ''foo
(QUOTE FOO)

CL-USER 24 > (read-from-string "'foo")
(QUOTE FOO)
```

The colon `:` is a package marker. If the package name is missing, the symbol is in the `KEYWORD` package.

We can give `foo` a value:

```
CL-USER 11 > (setq foo 10)
10
```

`foo` evaluates to its value.

```
CL-USER 12 > foo
10
```

A quoted symbol evaluates to the symbol.

```
CL-USER 13 > 'foo
FOO
```

We can't give `:foo` a value:

```
CL-USER 14 > (setq :foo 10)

Error: Cannot setq :FOO -- it is a keyword.
  1 (abort) Return to level 0.
  2 Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 15 : 1 > :top
```

`:foo` already has a value: itself.

```
CL-USER 16 > :foo
:FOO
```

Naturally a quoted `:foo` evaluates to `:foo`.

```
CL-USER 17 > ':foo
:FOO
```

The symbol `foo` is in some package, here `CL-USER`.

```
CL-USER 18 > (symbol-package 'foo)
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 92/256 internal, 0/4 external>
```

The symbol `:foo` is in the `KEYWORD` package.

```
CL-USER 19 > (symbol-package ':foo)
#<The KEYWORD package, 0/4 internal, 6230/8192 external>
```

Since `:foo` is the value of `:foo` we can also write:

```
CL-USER 20 > (symbol-package :foo)
#<The KEYWORD package, 0/4 internal, 6230/8192 external>
```

`:foo` is an abbreviation for `keyword:foo`. Thus the symbol is in the keyword package and it is exported.

```
CL-USER 21 > keyword:foo
:FOO
```

So keyword symbols are self-evaluation constant symbols in the keyword package. They are used as markers in data structures and in keyword arglists. The good things: you don't need to struggle with packages and they evaluate to themselves - so a quote is not needed.

Comment: Hmmm, but that's exactly what I don't get: If `'foo` evaluates to `foo`, and `:foo` evaluates to `:foo`, isn't it effectively the same? As you said, you can not assign a value to `:foo`, but neither can I assign a value to `'foo`, can I?

Comment: @GoloRoden: `'foo` is a shorthand notation for `(quote foo)`. Giving the list a value makes no sense. Since `:foo` evaluates to `:foo` it  is not necessary to quote it.

Comment: I think it's important to note that :foo evaluates to :foo, so it is self-evaluating, while 'foo evaluates to foo and as such is not. So it is not the same.

Comment: Also worth noting, might be: `(string= (symbol-name 'foo) (symbol-name :foo))`. I.e. The symbol name of a keyword does NOT contain the colon.

Answer (score 12):

### DIfferences between keywords and other symbols

[Rainer Joswig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23969318/1281433) describes the symbols themselves pretty well.  To summarize, though,  each symbol belongs to a package. `p::foo` (or `p:foo`, if it's external) is a symbol in the package `p`.  If you try to evaluate it as form, you'll get its symbol-value, which you can set with `set`, or `(setf symbol-value):

```
CL-USER> (set 'foo 'bar)
BAR
CL-USER> foo
BAR
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-value 'foo) 'baz)
BAZ
CL-USER> foo
BAZ
```

There's a special package named `keyword`. You can write `keyword::foo` if you want, but all of the keyword package's symbol are external, so you can write `keyword:foo` instead.  Because they're so commonly used, though, you even get a special syntax for them: `:foo`.  They've also got the special property that you can't set their value;  their values are themselves:

```
CL-USER> :foo
:FOO
CL-USER> (symbol-value :bar)
:BAR
```

And that's really all there is that makes keyword symbols special, in and of themselves.

### Keywords and other symbols as keyword names in lambda lists

What's probably a bit more important is that they are, by default, used as indicators for "keyword arguments" in lambda lists.  E.g.,

```
CL-USER> ((lambda (&key foo bar)
            (list foo bar))
          :bar 23 :foo 12)
(12 23)
```

> *I can see that keyword symbols are mainly used for named parameters,
>   but I was asking myself if it was not possible to implement this using
>   quoted symbols as well?*

The syntax for lambda lists actually lets you do a lot more customization with the keyword arguments.  A common thing is to specify default values:

```
CL-USER> ((lambda (&key (foo 'default-foo) bar)
            (list foo bar))
          :bar 23)
(DEFAULT-FOO 23)
```

You can also provide a variable name that gets bound to a boolean indicating whether the parameter was specified or not:

```
CL-USER> ((lambda (&key (foo 'default-foo foo-p) (bar 'default-bar bar-p))
            (format t "~{~A:~7t~A~%~}"
                    (list 'foo foo
                          'foo-p foo-p
                          'bar bar
                          'bar-p bar-p)))
          :bar 23)
FOO:   DEFAULT-FOO
FOO-P: NIL
BAR:   23
BAR-P: T
```

The full syntax for from [3.4.1 Ordinary Lambda Lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_da.htm) lets us do even more, though.  It's

```
lambda-list::= (var* 
                [&optional {var | (var [init-form [supplied-p-parameter]])}*] 
                [&rest var] 
                [&key {var | ({var | (keyword-name var)} [init-form [supplied-p-parameter]])}* [&allow-other-keys]] 
                [&aux {var | (var [init-form])}*])
```

Note that you can specify the `keyword-name`.  It defaults to the symbol in the keyword package with the same name as `var`, but you can actually provide it and specify your own "keywords".  This can be handy, e.g., if you want a descriptive keyword name but don't want such a long variable name:

```
CL-USER> ((lambda (&key ((:home-directory dir)))
            (list dir))
          :home-directory "/home/me")
("/home/me")
```

You can also use it to specify keyword names that aren't keyword symbols:

```
CL-USER> ((lambda (&key ((surprise surprise)))
            (list surprise))
          'surprise "hello world!")
("hello world!")
```

You can combine the two, too:

```
CL-USER> ((lambda (&key ((hidden-parameter secret)))
            (format t "the secret is ~A" secret))
          'hidden-parameter 42)
the secret is 42
```

You can mix that with default values as well, but you probably get the point by now.